# Wordpress admin.js Uncaught ReferenceError: tb_position is not defined

Tags: javascript, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an error on my WP setup. Everything was fine till yesterday, when ACF Image gallery plugin stopped working. It shows up, but it has some JS error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: tb_position is not defined  (admin.js?ver=3.8.1)

What could be the problem? Sometimes it works, but sometimes - it does not work.

Should I give you the list of all plugins used?

Comment: It's possible an error in some other plugin is stopping any further JavaScript running, so the ACF issue is a symptom rather than the problem being in ACF itself.  Google seems to imply "tb_position" is related to thickbox.  Do you have a thickbox plugin?  Can you disable it and test?

Comment: Actually, thickbox is built into WordPress - I can see references to it in (eg) wp-admin/js/theme.js.  Does the console show any other errors?  Any 404s?

Comment: console output 1: 'Consider using 'dppx' units instead of 'dpi', as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), not all, not all, not all, only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx)'

Comment: Output 2: Consider using 'dppx' units instead of 'dpi', as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: print, not all, (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), (min-resolution: 120dpi) post.php?post=65934&action=edit:1
Consider using 'dppx' units instead of 'dpi', as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch,so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: print, not all, (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),(min-resolution: 120dpi)

Comment: Output 3: Uncaught ReferenceError: tb_position is not defined

Comment: When i click somewehe that should use javascript, console outputs random errors

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue - turned out to be the the Per Page Widgets plugin. Edit the file  /wp-content/plugins/per-page-widgets/scripts/admin.js, and replace line 5 with:

```
if(typeof(tb_position) == "function"){
     var tb_position_old = tb_position;
}
```